# What is the price graph of Nikon cameras?

Tags: nikon, pricing

There are rumors that the D7100 and a new 16-85 will come out this year. I placed an order for this camera and lens in March this year, and I haven't got it yet because Nikon can't deliver the current 16-85mm.

As this is, to me as an amateur, a ***VERY*** expensive camera and lens, I don't want to waste money if the new versions of these (camera and lens) comes out this year. If I wait, and the price is going to be high, I'm going to be angry at myself for wasting my time waiting for a too expensive product to come out.

How does the price of the Nikon products evolve over time? Is it like regular products, they start expensive and get cheaper by time, or do they have a fixed price all the time from start to end?

Comment: * let us wait for the photokina event in Cologne, Germany in the mid of september this year, i am sure nikon is going to announce the D7100 at this event. (I am waiting for the d7100 aswell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The price basically starts high and ends low. You can expect to pay full retail for a camera (or lens) when it's introduced. After demand is sated price drops a little. As the product gets closer to end of life, price will drop more.

I doubt that the price you pay for a D7100 will be the same as the price for a D7000 today. There's some discount on the D7000 already ("instant rebate") and I'm sure the D7100 will initially cost full retail price.

Will the price difference be worth it? Well, you'll only know that after the D7100 is announced. And the D7000 price may even drop more after the 7100 is announced. But then, I am betting that in 2014 a D7200 will be released, and in 2016... The D7000 is an awesome camera; don't get caught up in the waiting game!

Comment: "Don't get caught up in the waiting game" - indeed.  I was waiting to see what Nikon was going to do with a D7100 or D400 but then I realized I was actually missing shots with my current camera (D3100 AF isn't so good) and the longer I waited, the more I missed.  So ya, waiting for an unannounced product is a no-no.

Comment: Great, then I'll go for it now! Thanks for the good answer!

Comment: I went for the D7000, and I'm glad I did. I've got so many shots that I would have missed with my D40 in terms of photo quality. The dynamic range is absolutely stunning. I've got some really good shots where the D40 would have blown out the highlights and burned out the blacks. "Don't get caught up in the waiting game!" This is really true.

Comment: `Don't get caught up in the waiting game` I think this is mostly true when you're running into the limitations of your gear. If you can't point to specific problems that would be solved by newer gear (like rfusca could - missing shots b/c autofocus), I'd just save my money. In fact, that's what I *did* :)